Equivalent html to contents of css class


.tooltip {
    /*background-color: #f9c;*/
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    position: relative;
    /*margin: 15px;*/
    text-align: center;
}
.tooltip::after {
    background-color: #333;
    border-radius: 6px;
    color: #fff;
    display: none;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 999;
}
.tooltip::before {
    background-color: #333;
    content: ' ';
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    z-index: 999;
}
.tooltip:hover::after {
    display: block;
}
.tooltip:hover::before {
    display: block;
}
.tooltip.bottom::after {
    content: 'bottom'; /* content is here */
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, calc(100% + 10px));
    transform: translate(-50%, calc(100% + 10px));
}
.tooltip.bottom::before {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, calc(100% + 5px)) rotate(45deg);
    transform: translate(-50%, calc(100% + 5px)) rotate(45deg);
}
<ul>
<li class="tooltip bottom">
        <img src="test.jpg" />
</li></ul>



It popup the tooltip with 'bottom' text
However I want to change this many variation.
If this is written in css I need to make many classes not only bottom, but also bottom1, bottom2,etc
So I want to write text bottom in html not in css.
Is it possible to do this?

Could you please attach the current output and the expected output?

https://css-generators.com/tooltip-speech-bubble

You had a mistake in HTML it's class not className.

You can use HTML data- attributes to insert content through CSS:


.tooltip {
    /*background-color: #f9c;*/
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    position: relative;
    /*margin: 15px;*/
    text-align: center;
}
.tooltip::after {
    background-color: #333;
    border-radius: 6px;
    color: #fff;
    display: none;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 999;
}
.tooltip::before {
    background-color: #333;
    content: ' ';
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    z-index: 999;
}
.tooltip:hover::after {
    display: block;
}
.tooltip:hover::before {
    display: block;
}
.tooltip::after {
    content: attr(data-direction); /* content is here */
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, calc(100% + 10px));
    transform: translate(-50%, calc(100% + 10px));
}
.tooltip::before {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, calc(100% + 5px)) rotate(45deg);
    transform: translate(-50%, calc(100% + 5px)) rotate(45deg);
}
<ul>
  <li class="tooltip" data-direction="bottom">
        <img src="test.jpg" alt="Image alt text" /> — This <code>li</code> has <code>data-direction="bottom"</code>
  </li>
  <li class="tooltip" data-direction="top">
        <img src="test.jpg" alt="Image alt text" /> — This <code>li</code> has <code>data-direction="top"</code>
  </li>
</ul>



